# How to make a sub property required in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Given the following setup:

```
interface Vegetable {
  vitamins?: string;
  foo?: string;
}

interface Fruit {
  seeds?: number;
  bar?: string;
}

interface Meat {
  flesh?: string;
}

interface Food {
  vegetable?: Vegetable;
  fruit?: Fruit;
  meat?: Meat;
}
```

How to make it so that the following interface is created:

```js
interface FoodWithSomeRequiredFields {
  vegetable: {
   vitamins: string; // (required)
   foo: string; // (required)
 };
 fruit: {
   seeds: number; // (required)
   bar: string; // (required)
  }
 meat?: {
   flesh?: string; // (not required)
  }
}
```

I can make an interface with the first level properties required, by doing:

```js
type FoodWithSomeRequiredFields = Required<Pick<Food, "vegetable" | "fruit">>;
```

This will throw an error when "vegetable" is undefined, which is good:

```js
const foodValidError: FoodWithSomeRequiredFields = {
  // Good: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ vitamins: string; foo: string; }'.
  vegetable: undefined,
  fruit: {
    seeds: 1,
    bar: "s",
  },
};
```

But the 'second level' property such as "vitamins" is not required:

```js
const foodInvalid1: FoodWithSomeRequiredFields = {
  vegetable: {
    vitamins: undefined, // Wrong: No error, but it should be required
  },
  fruit: {
    seeds: 1,
    bar: "s",
  },
};
```

[Example in a Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pedantic-khayyam-wchqnf?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.ts%3A48%2C51&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhx00063b6l68dmj5xs%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhx00023b6lzmkrnic8%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhx00033b6lwu6nnz33%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhx00053b6l3gyvtea0%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B73.78571830792043%252C26.214281692079567%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltzvsvhx00023b6lzmkrnic8%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhw00013b6l0hvytc9p%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A48%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A51%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A48%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A51%257D%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhx00023b6lzmkrnic8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhw00013b6l0hvytc9p%2522%257D%252C%2522cltzvsvhx00053b6l3gyvtea0%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhx00043b6l71dbf637%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhx00053b6l3gyvtea0%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhx00043b6l71dbf637%2522%257D%252C%2522cltzvsvhx00033b6lwu6nnz33%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzvsvhx00033b6lwu6nnz33%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

Comment: `interface FoodWithSomeRequiredFields extends Food` with the exact thing you posted in the question? That should ensure the all the nested properties stay in-sync, and a required property can always be assigned to an optional one. No reason to over-complicate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply have the interface with the required properties extend the interface with the optional ones:

```
interface Vegetable {
  vitamins?: string;
  foo?: string;
}

interface Fruit {
  seeds?: number;
  bar?: string;
}

interface Meat {
  flesh?: string;
}

interface Food {
  vegetable?: Vegetable;
  fruit?: Fruit;
  meat?: Meat;
}

// NOTE: extends
interface FoodWithSomeRequiredFields extends Food {
  vegetable: {
   vitamins: string;
   foo: string;
 };
 fruit: {
   seeds: number; // (required)
   bar: string; // (required)
  }
 meat?: {
   flesh?: string; // (not required)
  }
}

const foodValidError: FoodWithSomeRequiredFields = {
  vegetable: undefined, // Errors as expected
  fruit: {
    seeds: 1,
    bar: "s",
  },
};

const foodInvalid1: FoodWithSomeRequiredFields = {
  vegetable: {
    vitamins: undefined, // Errors as expected
  },
  fruit: {
    seeds: 1,
    bar: "s",
  },
};
```

That should ensure the all the nested properties stay in-sync, and a required property can always be assigned to an optional one. No reason to over-complicate it.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoQOYTHARgGxQG8AoZZAN2BwFtQBnAfgC5l6wpQMBuM5GAPYCWbDl14BfEiVCRYiFADEoAV2rJS5ehAgATJqxAqauaL3K44UEe04geJKTPDR4SZAFkIcMBr4xCegALGzF7SWlZVwVkRSFdP3IKTGw8QhF0LBwCCHN+VWoRZTUwPJpvMBEvHwjnOTcleIB1aiCAZQFygCUIAEc1KD1FYAh8fWQIAA9IEHG4gQTNShTswlYlymo4OhB6VltxPn4hfbCHZAlzGAKwdaPtPT3kIxMzZAB6d+QACkH+4EGugAlEdLFBTnYeB8vr8+gM9CDyFJkOUfCINgEIMFQpDuNCfiABL4-vDgXwpE4EAJdr5BAtUHB8MBdABRKBQATg2LNVodbpwgFDEZjejIAC8iXxAHF4qwACoATwADigAOQqWYQGCgPSq5DAUWE3xwej0YAYEBpFBgATIMDKtVETa0BgQ8THARu8IXVUAOj4ySyVtYGt0Wp1ugANP4bndyFodPpWABGaPx5Bg1gAInoWbTF2jl2kVJpHt0AEkQBRGczk6x5roWmB2p0ID1-oDhqNxhKloHUjk4-GqC7diHNdqQHpI-imhz7KwAHK26AcqAz3AqXzqYICFRjDMoEmC3Tk-PXEpDhOPFP5ixWbO5-MSQvcIA)